# onChange input value in map useState React Hooks

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, react-hooks, setstate

I've problem with useState input values.

What I got:

```
const [document, setDocument] = useState([
 {
    documentName: '',
    documentDate: '',
    documentInfo: '',
    documentContent: ''
  },
  {
    documentName: '',
    documentDate: '',
    documentInfo: '',
    documentContent: ''
  }
])


return ({
    document.map((item, index) => {
    return (
      <>
        <Grid item xs={3}>
          <label>Typ dokumentu:</label>
          <SelectInput
            fullwidth
            onChange={(e) =>
              setDocument({
                ...document,
                [e.target.name]: document.map((value, j) => {
                  if (index === j) value = e.target.value;
                  return value;
                }),
              })
            }
            value={document.documentName}
            name="documentName"
            register={register}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={1}>
          <label>Sekcja:</label>
          <SelectInput
            fullwidth
            onChange={(e) =>
              setDocument({
                ...document,
                [e.target.name]: document.map((value, j) => {
                  if (index === j) value = e.target.value;
                  return value;
                }),
              })
            }
            value={document.documentDate}
            name="documentDate"
            register={register}
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={1}>
          <label>Strefa:</label>
          <SelectInput
            fullwidth
            onChange={(e) =>
              setDocument({
                ...document,
                [e.target.name]: document.map((value, j) => {
                  if (index === j) value = e.target.value;
                  return value;
                }),
              })
            }
            value={document.documentInfo}
            name="documentInfo"
          />
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={1}>
          <label>SRS:</label>
          <SelectInput
            fullwidth
            onChange={(e) =>
              setDocument({
                ...document,
                [e.target.name]: document.map((value, j) => {
                  if (index === j) value = e.target.value;
                  return value;
                }),
              })
            }
            value={document.documentContent}
            name="documentContent"
          />
        </Grid>
      </>
    );
  });
}
)
```

What I want ? When I change for example documentName in second document then I've got:

```
[
{
 documentName:'',
 documentDate:'',
 documentInfo:'',
 documentContent:''
},
{
 documentName:'DOCUMENTEXAMPLENAME',
 documentDate:'',
 documentInfo:'',
 documentContent:''
}
]
```

I cant construct onChange function where I set this data in way which i described above.

I try to use handleChange method where:

```
  const handleChange = (e,index) => {
        const items = [...document]
        items[index][e.target.name] = e.target.value
        setDocument(items)
    }
```

But then this change proper value but in everyone of object.

Please help me !!

Comment: in case of handleChange function scenerio , how you are passing the values to handlechange function

Comment: Im invoke this in onChange function inside input components onChange {handleChange}

Answer (score 1):

Wrote my code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-ellis-6qbm8?file=/src/App.js)

Now I see you changed your question, provided same function as I wrote, But in sandbox it works well. Maybe there is something else in your original code?